# Youcompleme report 404 Client Error when quit vim

Tags: vim, youcompleteme

I install `YouCompleteMe` plugin in vim, bug I quit vim, I always get error like this:

```
Error detected while processing function <SNR>199_OnVimLeave:
line    1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/roger/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/autoload/../python/ycm/youcompleteme.py", line 345, in OnVimLeave
    self._ShutdownServer()
  File "/Users/roger/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/autoload/../python/ycm/youcompleteme.py", line 208, in _ShutdownServer
    SendShutdownRequest()
  File "/Users/roger/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/autoload/../python/ycm/client/shutdown_request.py", line 54, in SendShutdownRequest
    request.Start()
  File "/Users/roger/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/autoload/../python/ycm/client/shutdown_request.py", line 42, in Start
    TIMEOUT_SECONDS )
  File "/Users/roger/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/autoload/../python/ycm/client/base_request.py", line 81, in PostDataToHandler
    timeout ) )
  File "/Users/roger/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/autoload/../python/ycm/client/base_request.py", line 180, in JsonFromFuture
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "/Users/roger/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/third_party/requests/requests/models.py", line 840, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: http://127.0.0.1:59577/shutdown%
```

Here is my `YoucompleMe` config:

```
NeoBundle 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe', {
     \ 'build'      : {
        \ 'mac'     : './install.py',
        \ 'unix'    : './install.py',
        \ 'windows' : 'install.py',
        \ 'cygwin'  : './install.py'
        \ }
     \ }
let g:neobundle#install_process_timeout = 1500
"youcompleteme  默认tab  s-tab 和自动补全冲突
let g:ycm_key_list_select_completion=['<c-n>']
let g:ycm_key_list_select_completion = ['<Down>']
let g:ycm_key_list_previous_completion=['<c-p>']
let g:ycm_key_list_previous_completion = ['<Up>']
let g:ycm_complete_in_comments = 1  "在注释输入中也能补全
let g:ycm_complete_in_strings = 1   "在字符串输入中也能补全
let g:ycm_use_ultisnips_completer = 1 "提示UltiSnips
let g:ycm_collect_identifiers_from_comments_and_strings = 1   "注释和字符串中的文字也会被收入补全
let g:ycm_collect_identifiers_from_tags_files = 1
let g:ycm_server_keep_logfiles = 1
let g:ycm_server_use_vim_stdout = 1
let g:ycm_server_log_level = 'debug'

let g:ycm_autoclose_preview_window_after_completion = 1
let g:ycm_autoclose_preview_window_after_insertion = 1


" 跳转到定义处, 分屏打开
let g:ycm_goto_buffer_command = 'horizontal-split'
nnoremap <leader>jd :YcmCompleter GoToDefinition<CR>
nnoremap <leader>jd :YcmCompleter GoToDefinitionElseDeclaration<CR>
nnoremap <leader>gd :YcmCompleter GoToDeclaration<CR>


let g:ycm_seed_identifiers_with_syntax=1   "语言关键字补全, 不过python关键字都很短，所以，需要的自己打开

" 引入，可以补全系统，以及python的第三方包 针对新老版本YCM做了兼容
" old version
if !empty(glob("~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/cpp/ycm/.ycm_extra_conf.py"))
    let g:ycm_global_ycm_extra_conf = "~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/cpp/ycm/.ycm_extra_conf.py"
endif
" new version
if !empty(glob("~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/ycm/.ycm_extra_conf.py"))
    let g:ycm_global_ycm_extra_conf = "~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp/ycm/.ycm_extra_conf.py"
endif

" 直接触发自动补全 insert模式下
" let g:ycm_key_invoke_completion = '<C-Space>'
" 黑名单,不启用
let g:ycm_filetype_blacklist = {
      \ 'tagbar' : 1,
      \ 'gitcommit' : 1,
      \}
```

Comment: I am sorry, I don't know what is wrong, but I can not edit my question any more

Comment: Use YCM's issue tracker and/or mailing list.